# Execute Macro-Script on Remote Computer

Tags: vba, excel

I have an requirement to execute macro-script kept on remote machine. DCOM Configuration setting is not set to allow communication between two computers. Even it's not possible to change the DCOM setting in my scenario.

Can I achieve the same requirement using Remote Desktop connection and then invoking macro script (through VBA code)?

I don't know exactly how to invoke script kept on remote machine using VBA?

Any idea/suggestions welcomed!!

Answer (score 0):

This may not exactly answer your question, but may give you an idea.

I faced a the same problem with an application built in Access and the only way I could achieve this is by programming the macro I wanted to run into the application and then let the application periodically check a table on a share drive for "Go" command every few seconds.

On the share drive there was a table like this:

```
command_id | user       | command   
======================================
8          | "john.doe" | "update_me"
```

And all the applications were checking this table. If the app identified itself as user "john.doe", it decided to run the pre-programmed macro "update_me" and delete the row afterwards to prevent it from running again.

You can easily program more advanced stuff, like parameters, periodical execution etc.

It's not perfect, but it works quite nicely. Currently, I have the table on the SQL server and the command request takes cca 0.01s and I use it very often.